# Database error MySQL/CodeIgniter PHP when inserting a new value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-insert

When I am trying to insert a new value in a MySQL database, I have the following error:

---

Error Number: 1048

Column 'email' cannot be null

INSERT INTO emails(email)VALUES(NULL)

Filename: models/Model_email.php

### Line Number: 7

---

I had not this error when I was running the website on the local server, the error appeared on production. I code in PHP with the framework CodeIgniter.

The code is pretty simple though:

---

### Controler.php

```
public function addemail(){

    ini_set('display_errors','off');
    $this->load->model("Model_email","", true);
    $this->Model_email->addemail($_POST["email"]); 

}
```

---

### Model_email.php

```
public function addemail($email){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails(email)VALUES(?)";
    $data = array($email);
    $this->db->query($sql,$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

---

### HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="<?=site_url("/Controler/addemail")?>">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

When I add a var_dump($email) in the function in Model_email.php or a var_dump($_POST["email"]) in Controler.php, both page shows a NULL. However the method post in the form seems to be right.

Comment: I'm gonna try to answer your question, but please use better code conventions. Either go with camel case or snake case and stick with it. You shouldn't be using ini_set inside your function anyway. Unless that's called at the beginning of script execution it won't even do anything. Have you verified that there is in fact a value in $_POST['email']?

Comment: The error message says what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function addemail(){
    //ini_set('display_errors','off');
    $this->load->model('Model_email');
    $this->Model_email->addemail($this->input->post('email'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var_dump($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
```

to view what is submitted, by then you will see what is submitted by POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function addemail(){
    //ini_set('display_errors','off');
    if(isset($_POST["email"]) && $_POST["email"] && !empty($_POST["email"])){
         $this->load->model("Model_email","", true);
         $this->Model_email->addemail($_POST["email"]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one :

$data = array(
   'email' => $email

);

$this->db->insert('tablename', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')